# Sql Check constraint not working?

Tags: c#, sql

I am working on Inventory management system project ,i am using `c#` and `mssql` ,I am having a problem that i defined a check constraint on quantity column i.e `(QUANTITY>=0)` but it is not working .I wrote following query in C#:

```
INSERT INTO SALES 
   VALUES(@ITEM_MODEL
         ,@QUANTITY
         ,@AMOUNT
         ,@DATE_SALES
         ,''
         ,@TOTAL_PRICE
         ); 

UPDATE SALES 
         SET PROFIT=TOTAL_PRICE-(SELECT RATE 
                                   FROM ITEM_DETAILS 
                                  WHERE ITEM_MODEL=@ITEM_MODEL
                                 ) 
      WHERE ITEM_MODEL=@ITEM_MODEL; 

UPDATE ITEM_DETAILS SET QUANTITY=QUANTITY-(SELECT QUANTITY 
                                             FROM SALES 
                                             WHERE ITEM_MODEL=@ITEM_MODEL
                                           ) 
     WHERE ITEM_MODEL=@ITEM_MODEL; 

UPDATE ITEM_DETAILS SET AMOUNT = AMOUNT - (
                                       (SELECT RATE 
                                          FROM ITEM_DETAILS
                                         WHERE ITEM_MODEL=@ITEM_MODEL
                                       ) * 
                                         (SELECT QUANTITY 
                                            FROM SALES 
                                            WHERE ITEM_MODEL=@ITEM_MODEL
                                          )
                                       )
  where ITEM_MODEL=@ITEM_MODEL;
```

Another problem is that,i am executing it in a `try-catch` block for handle those exceptions where `quantity<0` ,but when i run it always goes in a `catch` block and show that quantity is zero whereas the `actual quantity is greater than zero`.

Following is the try-catch block in which query is executing:

```
 try
                {
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Nadeem-PC;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=TRUE");
                    da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ITEM_DETAILS VALUES(@ITEM_MODEL,@ITEM_NAME,@ITEM_DESCRIPTION,@VENDOR_NAME,@QUANTITY,@RATE,@AMOUNT,@INVOICE_NUM,@DATE)", con);
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ITEM_MODEL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtItemModel.Text;
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ITEM_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtItemName.Text;
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ITEM_DESCRIPTION", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtItemDescription.Text;
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@VENDOR_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtVendor.Text;
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@QUANTITY", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtQuantity.Text;
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@RATE", SqlDbType.Money).Value = txtRate.Text;
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@AMOUNT", SqlDbType.Money).Value = txtAmount.Text;
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@INVOICE_NUM", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtInvoice.Text;
                    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DATE", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;

                    con.Open();
                    da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();

                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Something wrong enters", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
```

Comment: INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT, UPDATE, UPDATE and another SELECT.. This is just one query or 4 different queries?

Comment: You might want to look into the `INSERT ... SELECT` form of `INSERT` statement. You should be able to write a single `SELECT` statement that constructs all of the columns that you actually want to insert into the table, and then insert that data directly, rather than performing an `INSERT` and then incrementally `UPDATE`ing it into the actual form it should have.

Comment: @Soner Gönül..it is one query performing multiple tasks

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever..can you please elaborate further ...i am actually performing multiple tasks using single statement?

Comment: Is it possible that `SELECT * FROM ITEM_DETAILS WHERE ITEM_MODEL=@ITEM_MODEL` returns more than ONE record? If so then you goes into CATCH block because of this not because of constraint.